# Can I ask a question about a way to connect

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm planning to do a trip only with my tablet and an external HD. As everybody knows, a normal tablet doesn't has enough space to store all pictures and videos I'm planning to take.

So, I'd like to know if there is a way to connect my camera on tablet, transfer the pictures to it, connect my HD on tablet and to transfer pictures which I had transfered to tablet to my HD.

Can I ask this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see how this could be a travel question. It's a technical question about cameras and tablets and depends on your model of camera and tablet.

Depending on the operating system that's running on your tablet, you may be able to find help on [Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/), or [Windows Phone Stack Exchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/). Check their topic list first, I don't know if hardware issues are on-topic there or only software issues.